# Displaying simple messages in Django

Tags: django

I am wondering what's the correct way to display simple message in Django. I am referring to simple message that doesn't deserve create dedicated template for. Stuff like: wrong activation key, your account has been activated you may start using it, etc. I would end up creating tens of templates if I create one for each error/info message.

Of course I need these message to be displayed in the layout of the current app.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a general template which accepts an error message variable which then it displays. Obviously with this approach you can use all the power of templates like extending, etc.

```
{% inherit 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ message }}
{% endblock %}
```

In the view:

```
def foo_view(request):
    message = 'Some message here'
    data = {'message': message}
    return render_to_response('message_template.html', data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use [django message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) ?

You can use it with any of your template

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use django messages framework as Pradnya Mhatre suggests.
I've usually put messages inside the base template like this:

**base.html:**

```
{% block messages %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      <div class="{{message.tags}} box">
        <p>
          {{ message|safe }}
        </p>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And inside the view you can put:

django.contrib.messages.add_message(request, django.contrib.messages.ERROR, message))

You can put ERROR, INFO and SUCCESS messages here.

Your view would look something like this:

```
import django.contrib.messages
import django.shortcuts

def some_view(request):
    do_something()
    django.contrib.messages.add_message(request, django.contrib.messages.SUCCESS, 'It worked \o/')
    return django.shortcuts.render_to_response(
        'template_that_extends_base.html',
        {},
        context_instance=django.template.RequestContext(request))
```